# Adonis test significativo, but Adonis pairwise test dont?

Tags: probability, paired-data, permanova

I'm analyzing microbiome data un R, and for beta diversity i got aitchison distance, unifrac (weighted and unweighted) and Bray Curtis. Then i usted Adonis test (from vegan)
Note: i'm looking for differences in gut microbiota composition from 14 insect species.

From Adonis test, p-value Is 0.001 afther 999 permitations (i guess, this Is significative); then, in order to check which of them are different i use pairwise.adonis and the issue starts here because all p-values (paired ones) are at less 0.1

I tried with other tools as PAST V4.0 but i have the same results, but this makes no sense for me.

What should i do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.